# Facebook Oauth field collection

Tags: 7, social-network, authentication-authorization

I have Facebook Oauth set up to receive a few fields.  They are mapped in the Configuration -> Facebook OAuth settings -> Field Mapping to fields I added to the account object.

When a facebook user tries to connect, they are prompted for permissions on these fields, and the user accepts.  However, the fields are not being captured to the fields they are mapped to.

Ideas??

Comment: Is this with the [Facebook OAuth](http://drupal.org/project/fboauth) module? If so, it sounds like it should be in the issue queue.

Comment: I assume it isn't working because I have something not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like I had my profile2 fields mixed up with my account fields.